# How to put multiple hyperlinks inside a Google Sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets

I tried multiple option, all returned me an error.

When I want to put one link in a cell this works fine :
`=HYPERLINK("mylink.com";"link1")`

Here is what I tried for multiple links (I also try changing the coma into semicolons and so on) :
`=HYPERLINK("mylink.com";"link1");HYPERLINK("mylink.com";"link2");HYPERLINK("mylink.com";"link3")`

If anyone knows how to do it, please let me know, thanks.

If

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put multiple hyperlinks in Google Sheets using the insert link shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Select the first work you want to hyperlink and press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> > Enter the link URL. Then repeat the same for the 2nd (or subsequent) word you want to hyperlink.

[image]